# PHP MySQl Chained Select

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have two drop downs that are populated from MySQL tables. In the MySQL tables they have foreign key restraints so the table "assets" has a column "department" that is linked back to the department table. So each asset has an associated department.

My first dropdown is "department" and I want the second dropdown to only show results from the selected department.

Here's my code.

```
<select id="location" name="location">
    <option value="">Select Asset Location</option>
 <?php
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=maintlog', 'root', '*******');
        #Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
        $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select id,name from location');
        $stmt->execute();
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
        {
            echo "<option value='$row[id]'>$row[name]</option>";
        }
  ?>
</select>
```

and for asset:

```
<select id="asset" name="asset">
    <option value="">Select Asset</option>
 <?php
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=maintlog', 'root', '*****');
        #Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
        $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select id,assetcode from assets');
        $stmt->execute();
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
        {
            echo "<option value='$row[id]'>$row[assetcode]</option>";
        }
  ?>
</select>
```

I have no idea where to start with this, I've done javascript chained selects but not with mysql/php.

Thanks

Comment: Javascript change event on the first dropdown. In the event make an ajax request and fill the second dropdown.

Comment: Nothing in this code as it stands can SELECT a Department. So you will have to load the Asset dropdown empty initially. Then when a Dept is selected using AJAX, request the Asset dropdown contents from a seperate PHP script, pass it the selected Dept_id and return assets based on that Dept_id and populate the Assets DD using javascript

Comment: Would it be easier if the values were in HTML as individual options. There's only around 10 locations and I can't foresee that growing...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With the all mighty parameter binding you can reduce the ammount of code you have to write and maintain.

Try the following example to get rid of your if (1), if (2), if (3) .....

```
if (filter_input(INPUT_GET, "smartload")) {
    sleep(1);
}

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$response[""] = "--";

/* Locations and asset  details data 
-------------------------------------------------------- */
if (filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'location')) {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=********', 'root', '********');
    #Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
    $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id,assetcode from assets where location=:getLocation');
    $stmt->bindParam(':getLocation', filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'location'), PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
    {
         $response ["$row[id]"]="$row[assetcode]";
    }
}
print json_encode($response);
?>
```

Bind the parameter to the query and execute. No need to repeat your code over and over.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to PHP. Much nicer way.

Answer (score -1):

I got there in the end. I ended up using a bit of Javascript and extra HTML. I also used jquery.chained for this to work correctly.

```
 $(function(){ 
                    $("#asset").remoteChained({
                        parents : "#location",
                        url : "selectData.php?smartload=1",
                        loading : "loading assets....",
                    });
                       });
```

So when location is loaded or selected it wakes up another PHP script which then uses IF statements to return values with different MySQL queries. (Example below).

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET["smartload"])) {
    sleep(1);
}

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$response[""] = "--";

/* Locations and asset  details data 
-------------------------------------------------------- */
if (isset($_GET["location"])) {
    if ("1" == $_GET["location"]) {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=********', 'root', '********');
        #Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
        $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id,assetcode from assets where location=1');
        $stmt->execute();
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
        {
             $response ["$row[id]"]="$row[assetcode]";
        }
    };

    if ("2" == $_GET["location"]) {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=********', 'root', '********');
        #Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
        $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id,assetcode from assets where location=2');
        $stmt->execute();
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
        {
            $response ["$row[id]"]="$row[assetcode]";

        }
    };

    if ("3" == $_GET["location"]) {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=********', 'root', '********');
        #Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
        $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id,assetcode from assets where location=3');
        $stmt->execute();
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
        {
             $response ["$row[id]"]="$row[assetcode]";
        }
    };
}

print json_encode($response);
?>
```

Then the ID of the dropdown "asset" is populated with the response in the php file javascript called for.

Thanks!

Comment: Yoda programming. Long time no see :-) Check my answer for a much shorter version of your code without the need to add an if for each location